# Change Release Build Exe Icon

Tags: build, icons, visual-studio-2019, release, .net-5

I have an application built in .NET 5 that I set a application exe icon for awhile back with a placeholder. I am now trying to replace said placeholder with a proper icon. However, for some reason when I build the release build it is still using the old placeholder icon despite me removing it from the project and setting it to the new one. On top of this, when I build in debug mode it uses the correct icon, but in release mode its using the old placeholder.

I have tried setting this in the project properties and specifying the path to the new icon in the .csproj file with no success from either attempt. Below is the contents of the .csproj, for context Logo is the new icon and LogoTemp was the old placeholder. Any help with this would be appreciated

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>LPG_Launcher</RootNamespace>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <Company>LowPoly Games</Company>
    <Authors>LowPoly Games</Authors>
    
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(ProjectDir)..\Build Assistant\bin\Release\Build Assistant.exe&quot; &quot;MakeDir$(ConfigurationName)&quot;&#xD;&#xA;if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (&#xD;&#xA;   del /S *.pdb&#xD;&#xA;   &quot;$(ProjectDir)..\Build Assistant\bin\Release\Build Assistant.exe&quot; &quot;MoveGames&quot;&#xD;&#xA;  &#xD;&#xA;   &quot;$(ProjectDir)..\Build Assistant\bin\Release\Build Assistant.exe&quot; &quot;CheckInstallers&quot;&#xD;&#xA;)" />
  </Target>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
    <PackageIcon></PackageIcon>
    <PackageIconUrl />
    <ApplicationIcon>Logo.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Installer\BuildAssistant.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Installer\InstallerVersionControl.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Fonts\BebasNeueBold.ttf" />
    <None Remove="Installer\BuildAssistant.exe" />
    <None Remove="Installer\InstallerVersionControl.exe" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Close.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\FG.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\GHGLogo.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\HCPlus" />
    <None Remove="Resources\HCPlus.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\ISPLogo.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Logo.ico" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Minimise.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="{d37e2a3e-8545-3a39-9f4f-31827c9124ab}">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>4</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>d37e2a3e-8545-3a39-9f4f-31827c9124ab</Guid>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="VersionAutoIncrementer.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>VersionAutoIncrementer.txt</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{508349b6-6b84-4df5-91f0-309beebad82d}" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="GameData\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Fonts\BebasNeueBold.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Close.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\FG.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\GHGLogo.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\HCPlus.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\ISPLogo.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Logo.ico" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Minimise.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />

  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (&#xD;&#xA;   &quot;$(ProjectDir)..\Build Assistant\bin\Release\Build Assistant.exe&quot; &quot;CleanDir$(ConfigurationName)&quot;&#xD;&#xA;)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone else encountering this problem, I've found the fix, or at least what will look like a fix. Open your Task Manager and restart Windows Explorer.

It would seem for some reason it was setting the correct icon at compile time but Windows Explorer itself wasn't picking up on it. Incredibly frustrating so I hope this is of help to anyone else encountering the same issue.